# primefaces messages in mac os x 10.11 el capitan disappear

Tags: ajax, primefaces, dialog

Since my install of el capitan (and new safari) the messages shown by the growl component immediately disappear after showing. sometimes it is so fast it is barely visible. in case of errors it is very annoying. anyone having this issue or knows how to solve this?

other people in the team don't have this behavior. very odd... we all use the same code though! running os x 10.11.1 with primefaces 5.2.13

Answer (score 0):

By putting ajax="false" on the button who calls the dialog and also on the button who closes the dialog, the messages keeps displaying. Apparently another developer has similar issues while working on firefox and also with yosemite. We had issues also in the past with dialog framework. Hoped they were fixed, but seems some nasty bugs are still arising from time to time.